# Blender Python API : How to select a collection in the Outliner?

Tags: python, collections, blender, outliner

I am trying to select a collection in blender by name. I was successful to find the collection in the outliner and make it an active collection using the following code

```
def recurLayerCollection(layerColl, collName):
        found = None
        if (layerColl.name == collName):
            return layerColl
        for layer in layerColl.children:
            found = recurLayerCollection(layer, collName)
            if found:
                return found
    
    layer_collection = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection
    layerColl = recurLayerCollection(layer_collection, 'Set')
    bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = layerColl
```

This highlights the collection I am looking for but does not actually select it, as shown in the picture.

[image: Outliner Screenshot]

As you can see, it highlighted the collection "Set", but it does not select it. How can I select it? I could not find anything in the API that can help. I will be grateful for any help or suggestion.

Comment: Any luck? I am running into the exact same issue and haven't found a solution yet. And this makes duplicating a collection fail if the active and selected collections are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
collection = bpy.data.collections["Collection"]
bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].view_layers['ViewLayer'].layer_collection.children[collection.name]
```

don't know if you have to adjust the above for more deeply nested collections, but this seemed to work.